# Unit vector tangent to parabola at $(x_0, y_0)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, conic-sections, curves

> Determine unit tangent vectors to curve $C$ at $(x_0, y_0)$, where:
>   $C : y=ax^2 + bx + c, a \neq 0$.

I know that unit tangent vector at point $P(x(t), y(t))$ is given by $\mathbf{T}(t)=\frac{\mathbf{r}^\prime(t)}{|\mathbf{r}^\prime(t)|}$, if $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a parametric smooth curve, but what is the parametric equation of parabola in such case?

This is my first time determining parametric form, so I am confused.

Comment: Try $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=at^2 + bt + t$

Comment: $+c$ instead of $+t$.

Comment: @caverac and what next?

Comment: @Angie Try $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=at^2+bt+c$ and call $\vec{r}(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, you already seem to know what to do with the parametric expression of a curve

Answer (score 2):

Note that every point on $C$ is defined by $(t, at^2 + bt + c)$. Thus, we define $\bar{r}(t) = \langle t, at^2 + bt + c \rangle$, a parametric function.

Additionally, you need not put it into parametric form. The derivative of the function which defines $C$ is given by $2at + b$ (by the power rule), which must be the slope of the tangent line. We know slope is change in $y$ divided by change in $x$, so we have that the unit tangent vector must be in the form

$$T(t) = \left\langle n, n(2at+b)\right\rangle $$

in order for the slope of $T(x)$ to be $2at + b$. Thus, simply solve for the $n$ such that $T(t)$ is a unit vector, and you have your unit tangent vector. In this case, we get

$$\sqrt{(n(2at+b))^2 + n^2} = 1$$
$$\sqrt{n^2 \cdot (2at+b)^2 + n^2} = 1$$
$$\sqrt{n^2((2at+b)^2 + 1 )} = 1$$
$$n \sqrt{(2at+b)^2 + 1} = 1$$
$$n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2at+b)^2 + 1}}$$

Comment: So this would give me the tangent unit vector at $(x(t), y(t))$, but how do I get such vector at $(x_0, y_0)$?

Comment: @Angie Note that $t = x_0$, and so just plug into $x(t), y(t)$.